# Get differences between members of a list

Tags: scala, collections

I have a list of values and want to reduce it to a list of differences between successive members. Is there a better way than this I have come up with (Trivial example) ?

```
val l1 = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)

val diffs = (l1 zip l1.drop(1)).map{case (x,y) => y - x}.sum
```

Comment: `List(a1, a2, a3, ... aN)` => `(a1 - a2) + (a2 - a3) + ... + (aN-1 - aN) == a1 - aN` => `diffs == l1.head - l2.last`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sure I've answered a very similiar question before, but I can't find it. Anyway, try `zipped` as it's more efficient and gives nicer syntax:

```
(l1 drop 1, l1).zipped.map(_-_).sum
```

Comment: Nice one, putting the dropped version first into the tuple

Comment: Neat. Also sliding solutions as below seems quite a lot slower on ad hoc benchmark I tried.

Answer (score 5):

I like use `sliding` for this use-case:

```
val l1 = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val diffs = l1.sliding(2).map{case List(x, y) => x - y}.sum
```

Try it [here](http://scalafiddle.net/console/a516a87cfcaef229b342c437fe2b95f7).

Answer (score 1):

You could use sliding

```
l1.sliding(2).map { case Seq(a, b) => b - a } .sum
```

But that's not much shorter. Also if you have a list, you could use `l1.tail` instead of `l1.drop(1)`.

I have once written the following extension method:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

implicit final class RichIterableLike[A, CC[~] <: Iterable[~]](val it: CC[A])
  extends AnyVal {
  def mapPairs[B, To](fun: (A,A)=>B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], B, To]): To = {
    val b     = cbf(it)
    val iter  = it.iterator
    if (iter.hasNext) {
      var pred = iter.next()
      while (iter.hasNext) {
        val succ = iter.next()
        b += fun(pred, succ)
        pred = succ
      }
    }
    b.result()
  }
}
```

With that:

```
l1.mapPairs(-_+_).sum
```

Comment: Using `drop(1)` rather than `tail` is a better choice because safe for empty sequences. E.g., `Nil.tail` raises an exception, but `Nil.drop(1)` returns `Nil`.